# i need a singer simulator or virtual singer?

Tags: sound, voice, signal-processing, human

i am going to generate artificial human voices like a singer

**do you know a tool with such ability ?**

[like this](http://www.myriad-online.com/en/products/harmony.htm)

Comment: Harmony Assistant + Virtual Singer

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't one. If you are looking for block harmonies like choir's "ahhh"'s there are software to do that, but as for an actual singer, it isn't yet possible (publicly available). Text to speech is still pretty rubbish sounding, even today because we're still learning what makes speech sound realistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're still interested you might want to check komponant.com
We're creating a technology that does exactly what you're looking for
Cheers

Comment: welcome , i am waiting for very **good news** on this project !

Answer (score 2):

Alter Ego Bones (free) Standalone, VST % AU 64bit - wi;; sing and speak whatever you type in to it, same presets are provided in English and Japanese, there are also add-on voices which are not free.
https://www.plogue.com/downloads.html

Answer (score 1):

Vocaloid is a Japanese vocals/singing generator

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocaloid

http://www.vocaloid.com/en/

Answer (score 1):

I created 2 virtual singer plugins that are pretty realistic, here are the links:

Comment: good luck 
very interesting and i shared them on facebook too
thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

vocaloid (English Chinese Japanese spanish and Korean)
 , utau(multiple languages) , MATA (Chinese), cevio (Japanese only)